# How to compare an item in an array to all items in other array and add it into shpreadsheet?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I'm developing a tool and currently I'm stuck with a problem.
I'm writing a code in GoogleAppScript (JavaScript) and I have two columns where I collect data. As a result I've two arrays. Let's call them `mainArray` and `checkArray`

I need a code doing this logic:

1. getting the 1st value of the mainArray, i.e. mainArray[0]
2. chenking the value if it's equal to checkArray[0], then checkArray[1]... checkArray[i]
3. if there's a match, then toss it to the garbage bin, and swith to the mainArray[1]
4. Checking mainArray[1] with all of the values from checkArray, as we did it in p.2
5. If there's no match with any vals from the checkArray add these value into the 3rd array (finArray)

I've done exaclty the opposite.

```
for (var j=0; j<checkArr.length; j++) {

     for(var i=0; i<mainArr.length; i++) {
  if(mainArr[i][0]!==''){
    if(checkArr[j][0]==mainArr[i][0])
    {
        Logger.log('not in the list'+mainArr[i][0])
        finArr.push(mainArr[i][0])
        break;
    }}
```

But I don't know how to get the code working as I described above.

Comment: see: [`Array#filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), but it looks like your `main` and `check` array have nested arrays? Post samples of each array for more specific answers.

Comment: when you collect data from a spreadsheet in google with .getValues you get a [[v1],[v2]] format. 

const a = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const b = ['c', 'a', 'd'];
let c = a.filter(word => b);

After running the code that check array a - I need to get only value 'b' because I don't have 'b' in the second array

Comment: `const c = a.filter(word => !b.includes(word));`

Comment: `getValues()` will return a 2D array, are you sure the example with simple arrays `a` and `b` corresponds to your current situation?

Answer (score 0):

```
 ` 
// The Arrays actually are one dimensional 
// I prefer to create a one dimensional array
// GetDataArray function creates one dimensional array
function GetDataArray(sht,rng) { 
    var Data = [] var i = 0; 
    Logger.log(' Sht Name %s\n rng %s,', sht.getName(), rng) 
    sht.getRange(rng).getValues() .forEach( 
        function (row) { 
           row.forEach( function (cell) { 
             //Logger.log(cell); 
             Data[i++] = cell }); } ); 
             return Data 
} //
 ......
var sht = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet() 
var rngMain = ....// Provide the range 
var rngCheck = ... 
var checkArr = GetDataArray(sht, rngCheck) 
var mainArr = GetDataArray(sht, rngMain) 
var finArr = [] 

mainArr.forEach( function(cell) { 
    if (cell == '') continue 
    if (checkArr.indexOf(cell) != -1) finArr.push(cell)})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function thefunc() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  let vs1 = sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),1).getValues().flat();
  let vs2 = sh.getRange(1,2,sh.getLastRow(),1).getValues().flat();
  let d = 0;
  vs1.forEach((r,i) => {
   if(~vs2.indexOf(r[0])) {
     sh.deleteRow(i+1-d++);//delete row
   }
  });
}
```